# TXT to CSV not splitting correctly (Python)

Tags: python, csv

I have this code which should split my txt file on the "comma with a space" looking like this:

```
Bobo Soso(bobososo), tu tu(tutu), bu bu(bubu)
```

into a csv file like this:

```
Bobo Soso(bobososo)
tu tu(tutu)
bu bu(bubu)
```

I use the following Code:

```
import csv

with open('test1.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
          lines = line.split(', ') #for line in stripped if line)
          with open('log.csv', 'w') as out_file:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file)
            writer.writerow('title')
            writer.writerows(lines)
```

But it splits it weirdly like this, with a comma after each :

```
B,o,b,o, S,o,s,o,(b,o,b,o,s,o,s,o)
t,u, t,u,(t,u,t,u,)
b,u, b,u,(b,u,b,u)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `writerows` takes a sequence of rows, and each row is a sequence of items. You're passing it a sequence of items, so each item is used as a row, and the letters of each item are used as the items in that row. You probably don't want to be doing a complete file write for each line in your original file. That does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: If you're already importing `csv`, why not use that also to read the file?

Comment: I'd recommend to use a [CSV reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for reading / parsing. With quoting this format can be more tricky than it looks like, and you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[writerows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) expects an iterable of rows where each row is also an iterable. The structure would normally be something like:

```
to_write =[
          [row_content1, row_content2, row_content2], #row 1
          [row_content1, row_content2, row_content2], #row 2
          ...
          ]
```

In your case, you have an array of strings ("lines"). A string in turn is also an iterable object:

```
for letter in 'I am a test':
   print(letter)
# out:
I
 
a
m
 
a
 
t
e
s
t
```

The above is what your writerows is also doing. To resolve you could either encapsulate each element in lines or you loop through lines yourself and call writerow([line[i]]).

It would however be a lot more pythonic to use pandas or comparable libraries. You will find plenty of instructions on SO or other sites on how to achieve that in your case.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation why it is not working - I used pandas as you suggested, and after a little research, it works fine now!